# Dropdown Menu wont appear

Tags: html, css, nav

I am working on my portfolio and I have stumbled upon a problem while working on my navigation bar. I am trying to hide the drop-down and make it appear on hover, but it is not showing up. I am also trying to center the dropdown menu to its parent which is `Portfolio`, but I could not figure out how to do so, so I just used padding which is a very poor method.

Here is the part of the code I think I am doing something wrong in, and a fiddle.

```
nav ul li:hover ul {
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ECvS/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML, the nested `<ul>` needs to be inside the closing `</li>`

```
<li>
    <a href="">Portfolio</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Experimental</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Motion Graphics</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Graphic Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Web Design</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

You can position your submenu relative to it's parent by setting your parent menu item to `position: relative;` which you already have, and adding these styles to your submenu, changing the top and left values to your requirements:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

I have updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3ECvS/4/)

Comment: ...and the OP needs to set some position values for the submenu.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks! Missed that part of the question on first read. I have updated my answer.